How can we change a pie-doughnut chart into an arrow ring chart?
Currently I've below design in echarts apache

and i want as below pie doughnut chart with arrows inside

Here is my current code:
var data = [
  { name: 'Label 1', value: 16.67, },
  { name: 'Label 2', value: 16.67, },
  { name: 'Label 3', value: 16.67, },
  { name: 'Label 4', value: 16.67, },
  { name: 'Label 5', value: 16.67, },
  { name: 'Label 6', value: 16.67, },
];

option = {
  series: {
    type: "pie",
    radius: ['50%', '70%'],
    left:"center",
    data: data,
  }
};


If doesnt has to be echarts, look at this example
